# Unique non-zero elements in a tensorflow tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have a tensorflow tensor `A`, i would like to know if there is a one-liner to find all unique values in `A` except `0` (or more realistically, a short way to do so). 
It would be quite similar the more pythonic :

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([2,2,2,0,1,3,3])
unique = np.unique(A)
unique = [x for x in unique if x!=0] 
print(unique)

>>> [2,1,3]
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `unique = unique[unique != 0]` (or `unique = unique[np.nonzero(unique)]`).

Comment: I have not made it clear, sorry, I would like to do it in Tensorflow. I just editted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TensorFlow you would do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    data_unique, _ = tf.unique(data)
    data_unique_nonzero = tf.boolean_mask(data_unique, tf.not_equal(data_unique, 0))
    print(sess.run(data_unique_nonzero, feed_dict={data: [2,2,2,0,1,3,3]}))
    # [2, 1, 3]
```

As a one-liner, you could do:

```
data_unique_nonzero, _ = tf.unique(tf.boolean_mask(data, tf.not_equal(data, 0)))
```

Although it is in principle less efficient, since you are first removing the zeros and then finding unique values, instead of the other way around.